# Куда и как выложить бота на vk_api чтобы он работал 24/7?

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Есть чат-бот работающий на vk_api написан на python. Как и куда его выложить чтобы он работал 24/7? Нужны ли для этого веб-фреймворки, если да, то какие можно использовать и в какую сторону копать? Какую книжку изучить или материал в интернете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого есть [heroku](http://heroku.com), [openshift](https://www.openshift.com/). Еще можно использовать Google Cloud Platform, AWS, Azure.